# Crystal Reports Using an IF formula with summary of summary fields

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I cannot find a solution or workaround that applies to my problem.

I have a complex report that includes several calculations at different levels.

GroupLevel4, which is `({Command.START_TIME}, "by second")`  has a formula field -- lets call it `{Formula_Field1}`.

It is defined as:

```
 If DistinctCount ({Command.RECORDED_TIME}, {Command.START_TIME}, "by second") >= Maximum({Command.DOCS_NEEDED}, {Command.START_TIME}, "by second") 
then 1 else 0.
```

It returns either 1 or 0.

Now I want to create a formula at Group3 level that says:

```
 If Sum({Formula_Field1}) >= Maximum({Command.DOCS_NEEDED}, {Command.ID}) 
then 'Y' else 'N'
```

However, I can't summarize Formula_Field1 because it's based on something that is already a summary.  I feel like I've tried everything.  I tried some suggestions I found about declaring variables, but I think they were more specific to a straightforward sum of a sum.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using running totals?

Comment: yes.  you can't summarize a running total in a formula either, so it didn't do what I needed.